# How to override class initialize method and use FactoryBot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm using FactoryBot with Rspec on rails.

I have a **SpecificKeyword** ruby class where I extend the `inittialize` method:

```
def initialize(args)
   super(args)
   # Init regexp field immediatly when creating keyword
   self.regexp = make_regexp(args[:specificity])
end
```

In my Rspec tests, i try to call this:
`@kw_ex = create(:specific_keyword, name: 'Test Keyword')`.

But I get this stack trace:

```
 ArgumentError:
        wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
      # ./app/models/specific_keyword.rb:19:in `initialize'
```

It looks like when instantiating a SpecificKeyword with FactoryBot, no args are passed to the init method. Is this a desired behavior, and if so, how am I supposed to proceed to keep using FactoryBot for my tests? It does work when I just do `SpecificKeyword.new(name:'Test')`.

If I do not override the `initialize` method, it does work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`FactoryBot` supports custom initializers looks like exactly your case:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :specific_keyword do
    transient do
      name { 'some default' }
    end

    initialize_with { new(attributes.merge(name: name)) }
  end
end
```

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/factory-girl-2-5-gets-custom-constructors

Comment: Great, it works. Just correct `initialize_with { SpecificKeyword.new(name: name) }` to `initialize_with { new(name: name) }` and it's perfect. Thank you !

Comment: I think this does not work if I specify other args afterwards: `create(:specific_keyword, name: 'test', arg2: 'arg2')`. The `arg2` is not sent to the `initialize` method. How can I keep the old syntax where I just pass a hash of params ?

Comment: @ypicard I assume other arguments are not attributes of your model?

Comment: It is a `field :arg2` type of my model

Comment: for attributes, I believe it should be something like: `initialize_with { new({your: 'custom'}.merge(attributes))` (`attributes` is a method which returns factory attributes (except transient ones) according to the documentation).